# Spring Cloud Stream + RabbitMQ Publisher confirm

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am planning to use Spring Cloud Stream for my project.
Is it there possible to use Publisher Confirms (aka Publisher Acknowledgements), i.e. registering a confirm callback as described in http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#cf-pub-conf-ret? Or are there other possibilities to receive an ack from RabbitMQ that it has received the message from the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; it's not supported. You can, however, set the `transactional` flag on the producer which cause an exception to be thrown if the send fails.

While publisher confirms are generally much "faster" than transactions, that is really only the case when you send a bunch of messages and wait for their confirmations later.

Since we are in a stream here; you'd be sending one message, then waiting for the confirm. That is not going to be significantly faster than just using a transaction.

If you want to use confirms; you would have to use a `RabbitTemplate` or Spring Integration outbound channel adapter directly, instead of the binder.

Comment: Can you explain how to set the `transactional` flag on the producer. I only found the `transacted` consumer property under **13.3.2 RabbitMQ Consumer Properties** in [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties).

Comment: It was missing from the docs; it is in the [SR3 Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.SR3/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbit_producer_properties) - that link is out of date and needs to be fixed.

Comment: is there any support for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is now supported.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-prod-props

See property confirmAckChannel